# Refactor authentication using react-router 3 to 4 in Meteor

Tags: meteor, react-router-v4

I'd like to update an authorization in meteor app using react- router v4 instead of v3.

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  const isAuthenticated = !!Meteor.userId();
  const pathname = browserHistory.getCurrentLocation().pathname;
  const isUnauthenticatedPage = unauthenticatedPages.includes(pathname);
  const isAuthenticatedPage = authenticatedPages.includes(pathname);

  if (isUnauthenticatedPage && isAuthenticated) {
    browserHistory.replace('/links');
  } else if (isAuthenticatedPage && !isAuthenticated) {
    browserHistory.replace('/');
  }
});
```

I've seen example from official react-router documentation page (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow). But still don't know to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great article by the Meteor Chef that explains how to use React Router V4. He shows you how to handle authentication too!

[Tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-react-router-v4)